# How to determine if Magento config is fetched from default, website or storeview

Tags: magento

E.g. config:

```
default:      some/xml/path: value_1
storeview_5:  some/xml/path: other_value
```

Now fetching:

```
// store 5
Mage::getStoreConfig('some/xml/path'); // >> other_value
// store 1
Mage::getStoreConfig('some/xml/path'); // >> value 1 (inherited from default)
```

I wish to know that storeview_1 has not its own config.

The best would be a method for fetching of config tree like:

```
default     => value_1
website_1   => website_value
storeview_1 => storeview_1_value
storeview_5 => other_value 
// omits empty configs for others or null them, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

the method `getStoreConfig` also accepts an optional store id, so just pass the store id as a second parameter
 `Mage::getStoreConfig('some/xml/path', $store_id);`